# routing to page name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing, custom-routes

is there a way i could route - http://localhost:3000/pages/1 to http://localhost:3000/home and all the other pages in my site i.e. - http://localhost:3000/pages/4 to http://localhost:3000/contact-us automatically?

I can do this the other way around using -

```
match "/home" => 'pages#show', :id => 1
match "/cars-for-sale" => 'pages#show', :id => 1
match "/contact-us" => 'pages#show', :id => 4
```

but need to do this in revers and automatically if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you really need is a redirect:

```
match "/pages/1", :to => redirect("/home")
match "/pages/:id", :to => redirect("/contact-us")
```

Note, that the order is significant - "Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified" (see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)